# asp.net mvc user authentication/permission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory

i'm new to asp.net mvc and starting the following project. The company wants an intra-net website for various groups of people to upload files to a database, run reports off the it and amend data in several master tables in the database. The company use Active Directory and do not want the users to log in again to use the web site. The website will have different sections for various groups and the user's access to a particular page should be controlled from a database.

So far this is what i've come up with

1. changed the membership provider to link to the active directory server ([based on Mike's blog post](http://helios.ca/2009/05/04/aspnet-mvc-forms-authentication-with-active-directory/))
2. removed AccountController and the Views/Account folder
3. created a custom authentication class based on [this link](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2009/02/17/custom-authorization-with-aspnet-mvc/)

I need to pull from a table in the database, based on user's AD id, his "role" (int), then cast it into the relevant SiteRoles. Would implementing this query in CustomAuthorizeAttribute be adviseable? is there a better place to pull the data from the table and store it somewhere so it can be reused rather than having to run a database query every time AuthorizeCore is called (which will happen whenever a user invokes a controller/action)?

Answer (score 4):

A custom `AuthorizeAttribute` is definately the way to go as it will be applied **before** all other action filters.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 3):

I would use the out-of-the box `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` rather than a custom attribute (because reinventing the wheel is generally bad, and reinventing the wheel in the area of security is bad to the point of incompetence in most cases), and the [AzMan Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998336.aspx) to map AD groups and accounts to app roles.

This pairing gives you far more features out of the box (e.g., standardized GUI interface for permissions) than custom code, and is probably more secure, too.

Answer (score -1):

You could do everything you want using the MVC provided FormAuthentication.  Just create your custom ValidateLogOn method in the AccountController.  Example:

```
public ActionResult LogOn(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
        {

            if (!ValidateLogOn(userName, password))
            {
                return View();
            }

            FormsAuth.SignIn(userName, rememberMe);
            Session["userlogin"] = userName;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```

Where your ValidateLogOn will be something like:

```
        private bool ValidateLogOn(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("username", "You must specify a username.");
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("password", "You must specify a password.");
            }
            /*
             * Do your LDAP Validation stuff (DB queries, etc) here.
             */
         }
```

Comment: a problem is a requirement i have - that the users do not need to enter their username or password since they have already logged in to AD on your computers.